# how to have tcp act more like udp

Tags: sockets, tcp

is there a way to have tcp act more like udp?  Im currently using lua sockets and have set the tcp no_delay option, is there a way to disable or set the  acknowledgement to timeout?

Comment: Define "have TCP act more like UDP". THere is certainly no way to disable the acknowledgement timeout in TCP, although you may be able to configure it locally. If you want UDP, use UDP.

Comment: yeh only the functionality through the nat is why im thinking of using tcp.  i guess you cant make tcp less reliable via config options..